# Fast resize picture tool/script

Tags: php, image, image-processing, image-resizing

I have a lot of images (500,000 +) in a folder on the server organized by date. I made a PHP script to copy and crop each JPG file on a subfolder (thumb), but it's very slow since PHP doesn't support multithreading.

I want advice on how to proceed. Is Python a good option for this? Is there a good tool, or how can I improve my resize function?

You can also take a look to my [PHP Code](https://gist.github.com/4020431)

Comment: Is multithreading even going to help here? Unless you were to work on more than one picture at time, that is. Even if you were to use another language, you have to take advantage of the multithreading aspect, it does not just start using all of your CPUs automatically.

Comment: Download them process them and upload them?

Comment: @Chris, I'm doing that... but still slow o.O

Comment: @thatidiotguy, assume that I have the files on my computer

Comment: Just for the record: you could also use [ImageMagicik Command-line Tool](https://imagemagick.org/script/convert.php) to resize on the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in PHP without any problem, simulating threads instead of using them directly. Actually, PHP doesn't have native threads (you can eventuall¥ use libraries but that's not very useful in your case).

In your code, instead of calling :

```
static::Crop($file,$destination,$tn_w = 300,$tn_h =200,$quality = 100,$wmsource = false);
```

Why not doing :

```
$array = array($file, $destination, $tn_w = 300, $tn_h = 200, $quality = 100, $wmsource = 0);
$command = "/usr/bin/php crop.php";
foreach ($array as $arg)
{
  $command .= ' ' . escapeshellarg($arg);
}
exec("$command &"); // note the & which release your execution
usleep(100000);
```

And you put your cropping function inside `crop.php`, and then call it like :

```
list($exec, $file, $destination, $tn_w, $tn_h, $quality, $wmsource) = $argv;
static::Crop($file,$destination,$tn_w = 300,$tn_h =200,$quality = 100,$wmsource = false);
```

This will do the job.

You can also simulate mutexes using a file if you want to avoid usleep and control how many crops are running at once, that's really up to you. You definitely can do such work in PHP.

Comment: Instead of the for loop you could do `$command .= ' "' . implode('" "', $array). '"';`

Comment: What's the reason for the `usleep(100000);`?

Comment: To prevent [bombforking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb). OP has 500k pictures to crop, and without sleeps, you'd run 500k execs at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

But php cgi support multithreading. Why not using exec()? Or you can use a shell script and for the conversion php cgi?

Answer (score 0):

by Use This class

```
<?php
class thumbnail_images {

// get
var $PathImgOld;
var $PathImgNew;
var $NewWidth;
var $NewHeight;

// tmp
var $mime;

function imagejpeg_new ($NewImg,$path_img) {
    if ($this->mime == 'image/jpeg' or $this->mime == 'image/pjpeg') imagejpeg($NewImg,$path_img);
    elseif ($this->mime == 'image/gif') imagegif($NewImg, $path_img);
    elseif ($this->mime == 'image/png') imagepng($NewImg, $path_img);
    else return(false);
    return(true);
}

function imagecreatefromjpeg_new($path_img) {
    if ($this->mime == 'image/jpeg' or $this->mime == 'image/pjpeg') $OldImg = imagecreatefromjpeg($path_img);
    elseif ($this->mime == 'image/gif') $OldImg = imagecreatefromgif($path_img);
    elseif ($this->mime == 'image/png') $OldImg = imagecreatefrompng($path_img);
    else return(false);
    return($OldImg);
}

function create_thumbnail_images() {
    $PathImgOld = $this->PathImgOld;
    $PathImgNew = $this->PathImgNew;
    $NewWidth = $this->NewWidth;
    $NewHeight = $this->NewHeight;

    $Oldsize = @getimagesize($PathImgOld);
    $this->mime = $Oldsize['mime'];
    $OldWidth = $Oldsize[0];
    $OldHeight = $Oldsize[1];

    if ($NewHeight == '' and $NewWidth != '') {
        $NewHeight = ceil(($OldHeight * $NewWidth) / $OldWidth);
    }
    elseif ($NewWidth == '' and $NewHeight != '') {
        $NewWidth = ceil(($OldWidth * $NewHeight) / $OldHeight);
    }
    elseif ($NewHeight == '' and $NewWidth == '') {
        return(false);
    }

    $OldHeight_castr = ceil(($OldWidth * $NewHeight) / $NewWidth);
    $castr_bottom = ($OldHeight - $OldHeight_castr) / 2;

    $OldWidth_castr = ceil(($OldHeight * $NewWidth) / $NewHeight);
    $castr_right = ($OldWidth - $OldWidth_castr) / 2;

    if ($castr_bottom>0) {
        $OldWidth_castr = $OldWidth;
        $castr_right = 0;
    }
    elseif ($castr_right>0) {
        $OldHeight_castr = $OldHeight;
        $castr_bottom = 0;
    }
    else {
        $OldWidth_castr = $OldWidth;
        $OldHeight_castr = $OldHeight;
        $castr_right = 0;
        $castr_bottom = 0;
    }

    $OldImg = $this->imagecreatefromjpeg_new($PathImgOld);
    if ($OldImg) {
        $NewImg_castr = imagecreatetruecolor($OldWidth_castr, $OldHeight_castr);
        if ($NewImg_castr) {
            imagecopyresampled($NewImg_castr, $OldImg, 0, 0, $castr_right, $castr_bottom, $OldWidth_castr, $OldHeight_castr, $OldWidth_castr, $OldHeight_castr);
            $NewImg = imagecreatetruecolor($NewWidth, $NewHeight);
            if ($NewImg) {
                imagecopyresampled($NewImg, $NewImg_castr, 0, 0, 0, 0, $NewWidth, $NewHeight, $OldWidth_castr, $OldHeight_castr);
                imagedestroy($NewImg_castr);
                imagedestroy($OldImg);
                if (!$this->imagejpeg_new($NewImg, $PathImgNew)) return (false);
                imagedestroy($NewImg);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        return(false);
    }

    return(true);
}

}
?>
```

Now use it

```
$width = $_REQUEST['img_width'];
$height = $_REQUEST['img_height'];
// example
$obj_img = new thumbnail_images();
$obj_img->PathImgOld = 'Old_image.jpg'; // Image for resize
$obj_img->PathImgNew = 'my_image_new_formSubURLkki.jpg'; // New Image Path
$obj_img->NewWidth = $width;
$obj_img->NewHeight = $height;
if (!$obj_img->create_thumbnail_images()) echo "error"; 
else {
    echo 'Image Maked andsave in directory';
}
```

Comment: This is just an algo i will upload complete script for image resizing soon. I used this in my website
http://hdwallpapershop.com

Comment: Now complete script is added